# contentoffset during flick gesture

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, mkmapview

Does anyone else notice that the contentOffset of UIScrollView doesnt update during a flick gesture?

It only updates after the flick gesture has totally completed, when the flick gesture is finished.

After the finger has left the screen, the scrollview keeps moving, in the decelerating phase. but this isnt reflected in the contentOffset of the UIScrollView.

Is there a way to track where the contentOffset is during the decelerating part of the flick gesture?

I have an OpenGL layer on top, and i want it to move with the scrollView. Can't seem to get the right info out of the scrollview though...

Thoughts?

thanks,

michael

Comment: Are you ruling out making the EAGLLayer a sublayer of UIScrollView's content view?  That's certainly the simplest solution.

Comment: hm. even if i were to do this.. id have to somehow translate the flicks into OpenGL... if the EAGLLayer is the size of the window.

Either that, or I'd be scrolling through an OpenGL layer thats larger than the screen... I'd wonder how intensive that is...

And I heard it was bad to mix UIKIT and OpenGL.

good idea though, i hadnt thought of that one...

I just saw this calayer presentationview, which has information on where the layer is during animation. 

i will try this out. 

will update.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `-scrollViewDidScroll:` is called continuously during animations.

Comment: ok thanks hatfinch.

heres a complication: the uiscrollview is embedded inside the mkmapview....

does that make sense? im getting the scrollview thats used by the mkmapview... and i bet that the mkmapview already has a delegate for the scrollview. 

is it possible to make two delegates? how do i look inside the mkmapview to know how its using the embedded scroll view...?

thanks a lot!

Comment: yup, my worst suspicions were confirmed.. the mkmapview is already using the delegate... and setting our own breaks mkmapview (specifically, when im scrolling now, the map doesnt load up bc the delegate isnt getting info on the scroll). ill try adding some sort of code that passes along the messages to mkmapview

Comment: not working... the information passed to the delegate isnt up to date.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't up to date"?

Comment: Just subclass MKMapView, override the delegate methods of UIScrollView but at the beginning send a message to -super.